# How to resolve Plesk user permission issue on Ubuntu 12.04 after Tar issue?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, permissions, plesk

I have transferred my files from server1 to server2 after a problem. Anyway, what I did, I transferred the files directly as ROOT from server 1 o server 2 like the following :

```
SSH-server1 : /var/www/vhosts/mydomain/
```

to

```
SSH-server2 : /var/www/vhosts/mydomain/
```

My problem now is with Permissions in Plesk, as I transferred the files as ROOT, Plesk disable permission option in USER column like the attached image https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCig5.jpg, it assigned all the files to ROOT user, instead of mydomain user.

There is a way to resolve this issue, maybe by changing this assignment ? to be able to use permission again in Plesk ?

Thanks for yoru help.

Comment: By the way, and after hours of searching, I'm still not able to know about it is possible to do that, so I understand now why it is not easy to get support for this problem. Anyway, I will try to contact Plesk's support and let you know what they will say.

Answer (score 0):

```
chown -R <subscription-ftp-user>:<subscription-ftp-user> /var/www/vhosts/mydomain
```

You can find subscription's ftp user name in Plesk GUI.